# Компонент DateTimePicker в C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder, datetimepicker

Существует ли возможность ввода с клавиатуры года непосредственно в маленькое окошко, которое выделено? Чтобы не приходилось использовать стрелки справа от окошка.
Если да, то как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить эту проблему быстро - не получится. То о чём вопрос - баг самого windows-компонета, т.к. DateTimePicker является "обверткой" к WinAPI DateTimePicker который системный.

Почитать о нём можно тут [msdn](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/date-and-time-picker-controls)

Ваш вид - это WinXP вариант, в новой версии Windows он будет выглядеть иначе. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не нашёл у DateTimePicker собственного контекста для дочерних елементов. Теоретически - можно отследить события, и как-то перебить такое странное поведение  - но это будет по-сути то же самое что создать новый. Кроме того, в разных версиях windows этот компонент может по-разному выглядеть.

Если нужно редактировать год - установите курсор в верхнем окне после "-apr-". Так же можно воспользоваться клавишами вверх/вниз.

Другой вариант - поищите другие компоненты аналогичные DateTimePicker на сайтах по делфи.